# How to: Refresh a page between certain times on a day of the week?

Tags: php, jquery, date, time, refresh

I'd like for a web page to automatically refresh between certain times on a specific day of the week (between 9am and 12pm on Wednesdays). New content will be made available on the page, and I want to ensure someone sees the content without having to remember to refresh the page themselves. Not sure how to finish getting this to work. Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php
    $page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $sec = '600000'; // 10 minutes
    date("Y-m-d");
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
    $time= date('w H:i'); // Day Hour:Minute
    if($time >= '3 09:00' && $time <= '3 12:00') { //after 9am and before 12pm on Wednesday
        echo '<style type="text/css">.element { display:block; }</style>';
    } else {
        echo '<style type="text/css">.element { display:none; }</style>';
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function() {
        window.location.href = '<?php echo $page; ?>';
    },<?php echo (int)$sec; ?>); 
</script>
```

Even refreshing just once may be more ideal...

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's better to put your javascript in a php variable ($js).

Better to use setTimeout instead of using setInterval if you want only refresh once.

```
  <?php
        $js = '';
        $page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $sec = '600000'; // 10 minutes
        date("Y-m-d");
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
        $time= date('w H:i'); // Day Hour:Minute
        if($time >= '3 09:00' && $time <= '3 12:00') { //after 9am and before 12pm on Wednesday
            echo '<style type="text/css">.element { display:block; }</style>';
            $js = '<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function() { location.reload(); }, ".(int)$sec."); </script>';
        } else {
            echo '<style type="text/css">.element { display:none; }</style>';
        }
        
        echo $js;
    ?>
```

Tell me if it's what you need.

Comment: Thank you, @The_Death_Raw. Unfortunately, the page keeps cycling through refreshing, and eventually times out / becomes unresponsive. It doesn't refresh every 10 minutes (I even changed it to 30 seconds for quicker testing).